# Python dbf Module, write fine, but not appear on VFP until pack() table

Tags: python-3.x, visual-foxpro, dbf

I use a dbf python module by Ethan to write records in a Visual Fox Pro dbf Table. I did this to append:

```
import dbf
Db = dbf.Table ('table.dbf')
Db.open (mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)
record = { 'NUMERO' : 1, 'TIPO' : 'TA' } # It's a simplified record, real record it's so long.
Db.append( record )
Db.close()
```

The record is added to the dbf file, I can see on VFP Table, using VFP command window, but not appear in the VFP program. At first, I've supposed something happened inside VFP flow, but when I make a manual PACK with DBF Manager, the records appear correctly inside VFP Program, the record not appear in DBF Manager before do a PACK in the table neither.

I try to do

```
import dbf
Db = dbf.Table ('table.dbf')
Db.open (mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)
record = { 'NUMERO' : 1, 'TIPO' : 'TA' } # It's a simplified record, real record it's so long.
Db.append( record )
Db.pack() # Pack before close.
Db.close()
```

But it's not working. Does somebody know what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

The VFP program is probably using an index, and the Python `dbf` module doesn't support index files.  I suspect that a `REINDEX` command would also show the new record.

Comment: I was suspecting the same thing, but then there is no way? Will there be support for indexing in your dbf module for python in the future?

Comment: It's on the to-do list, but finding time is challenging.  :(

Comment: I know, I understand you !

Comment: I did the REINDEX table and works like a PACK, I need to open table in Exclusive mode to do It, It's a multiuser, many users usually have It's open. Can I do something to add new records via python and that this appear in the vfp table? Reindexing table always going to require open the table in exclusive mode?

Comment: @user12908153: Not that I know of, but I am not a VFP expert.

Comment: My solution is so: I write data to csv file, via python-module "watchdog" a little VPF-prog is then triggered for importing data with open indexfile(s). But it would really help, if indizes would be supported by dbf-module directly. :-)